# how to shuffle a Concatenated Tensorflow dataset

Tags: tensorflow, dataset

I have multiple tensorflow datasets that have the same structure.
I want to combine them to a single dataset. using
[tf.dataset.concatenate](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#concatenate)

but i found that when shuffling this combined dataset, the dataset is not shuffled on the scale of whole datasets. But shuffled in each separated dataset.

Is there any method to solve this?

Answer (score 3):

When you concatenate two `Dataset`s, you get the elements of the first then the elements of the second. If you shuffle the result, you will not get a good mix if your shuffling buffer is smaller than the size of your `Dataset`.

What you need instead is to interleave samples from your dataset. The best way if you are using TF >= 1.9 is to use the dedicated [`tf.contrib.data.choose_from_datasets`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/choose_from_datasets) function. An example straight from the docs:

```
datasets = [tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors("foo").repeat(),
            tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors("bar").repeat(),
            tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors("baz").repeat()]

# Define a dataset containing `[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]`.
choice_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.range(3).repeat(3)

result = tf.contrib.data.choose_from_datasets(datasets, choice_dataset)
```

It is probably better to shuffle the input datasets if preserving the sample order and/or their ratios in a batch is important.

If you are using an earlier version of TF, you could rely on a combination of `zip`, `flat_map` and `concatenate` like this:

```
a = tf.data.Dataset.range(3).repeat()
b = tf.data.Dataset.range(100, 105).repeat()

value = (tf.data.Dataset
  .zip((a, b))
  .flat_map(lambda x, y: tf.data.Dataset.concatenate(
    tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors([x]),
    tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors([y])))
  .make_one_shot_iterator()
  .get_next())

sess = tf.InteractiveSession()

for _ in range(10):
  print(value.eval())
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a way to do the trick with `tf 1.4`?

Comment: The background is:  1. the input dataset is word sequences. 2. the reason I use this scheme is that I should read different vocabulary files according to the first word of input sentence. 3. now I can get a python list, in which each item is a tf.dataset.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from tensorflow 1.9 you can also make use of the [sample_from_datasets](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/sample_from_datasets) method.

For example, the following code

```
datasets = [tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors("foo").repeat(3).apply(tf.data.experimental.enumerate_dataset()).repeat(),
        tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors("bar").repeat(3).apply(tf.data.experimental.enumerate_dataset()).repeat(),
        tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors("baz").repeat(3).apply(tf.data.experimental.enumerate_dataset()).repeat()]

dataset = tf.data.experimental.sample_from_datasets(datasets) # from 1.12
# dataset = tf.contrib.data.sample_from_datasets(datasets) # between 1.9 and 1.12

iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator();next_element = iterator.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for i in range(10):
        print(sess.run(next_element))
```

will print

```
(0, b'bar')
(0, b'foo')
(1, b'bar')
(0, b'baz')
(2, b'bar')
(1, b'foo')
(1, b'baz')
(2, b'foo')
(2, b'baz')
(0, b'foo')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure, but you might want to look into the order in which you call different operations on your dataset object. The behaviour of `shuffle()` can vary dependent on the order. See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51650033/tensorflow-dataset-shuffle-behavior-when-used-with-repeat-and-batch) question which might be related.

Answer (score 0):

What is your shuffle buffer size?

For example, if you have 3 datasets, each containing 1000 items, then you need to apply shuffle(3000) to randomize the order of all the items.

Here is an example:

This should shuffle all the 3000 items:

```
dataset = dataset1.concatenate(dataset2).concatenate(dataset3)
dataset = dataset.shuffle(3000)
```

However, this will ***not*** shuffle the whole dataset:

```
dataset1 = dataset1.shuffle(1000)
dataset2 = dataset2.shuffle(1000)
dataset3 = dataset3.shuffle(1000)
dataset = dataset1.concatenate(dataset2).concatenate(dataset3)
```